# Angular Dependency Issue with ngx-favicon

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Can someone explain to me why I cannot use `npm install ngx-favicon`?

```
npm install ngx-favicon
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: online-booking-portal@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~14.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from ngx-favicon@4.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-favicon
npm ERR!   ngx-favicon@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

These are the Angular versions installed:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 14.2.10
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 9.1.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.10
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.10
@angular/cli                    14.2.10
@schematics/angular             14.2.10
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.7.3
```

My understanding is that 4.0.1 for ngx-favicon is looking for at least version 13.0.0 of @angular/common (the ^13.0.0 part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dependency mismatch.

[^version] means [Compatible with version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies).

In the above error `ngx-favicon@4.0.1` requires `@angular/common` version `@^13.0.0` And the actual `@angular/common` version is `@14.0.7`

In this case, `@ngx-favicon` is compatible with version up to `<14.0.0`

Use the option `--legacy-peer-deps` to install the package ignoring the conflict.

```
npm install ngx-favicon --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: does this mean that there are going to be issues using ngx-favicon and the major version number is not correct?

Comment: It doesn't have to exist issues using the library with a major version. Use version control, check it and see if everything works fine.  I've created a pull request to upgrade the peer dependencies and solve the problem.